# Django search in string value of modelfield

Tags: django, django-models

This is a string value that I want to store in a model.CharField:

```
"8;4,8;0;D;0;0;"
```

Is there a way of efficiently querying entries in search for entries where the last value only would be 1? Or for example where one of the two values after the first semicolon would be 6?

Or is this a case where it's better to create seperate fields for each value? Which would be unfortunate because than I would need to create 60 or more fields instead of around 10.

Answer (score 2):

Storing values that way means that your database is not in "First normal form" (1NF - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Normalizing your database makes it easier to search (amongst many other benefits).

Check the 3NF wikipedia article for more details (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and references.